# How to handle 'Uncaught:exception' in cypress cucumber test

Tags: javascript, error-handling, cypress, uncaught-exception, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I want to handle uncaught exceptions occurs while running cypress tests using cucumber.I have to apply the settings before all the feature tests in all modules. How can I handle that?

I tried  this way, cy.on function in cypress config, but it is showing error for me.

```
 async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      on(
        'file:preprocessor',
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        }),
        
      );
 

    cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
     
         return false
      })
     
      return config;
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use the code in a different place, either in `cypress/support/e2e.js`

```js
// cypress/support/e2e.js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

or inside the step file

```js
// cypress/e2e/step-definition-for-feature-x.ts
import { When, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})

When('tests while ignoring an uncaught exception', () => {
  ...
```